# Bottom Navigation Bar overlaps view above it

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have following view hierarchy

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    >

    ...

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/am_bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/am_fade_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layerType="hardware"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/am_tracker_over_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want for `am_tracker_over_layout` to be shown ahead everything else, but `BottomNavigationView` gets ahead. Made it transparent for clarity.

[image: BottomNavigationView overlaps view above it]

Tried googling it. Read that the last view in group is shown ahead, but it doesn't seem to be true with `BottomNavigationView`.

So, how can I explicitly move `BottomNavigationView` behind some other view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to set bottom navigation view elevation. try to add following property in bottom navigation view tag

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: to be precise `elevation` and/or `translationZ`, probably second one in this case, but worth trying both

Comment: It worked, thanks! But it also works only above API 21 and I'm targeting API 19. Is there any API 19 compatible way to do the same thing?

Comment: @Krill you already using material lib try to replace android prefix to app
`app:elevation  = "0dp"`

Comment: Also i had to set `app:elevation="10dp"` in `am_tracker_over_layout`

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_above` property to `FrameLayout` to place it above the `BottomNavigationView` like below:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/am_tracker_over_layout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/am_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Or if you want to overlap it on `BottomNavigationView` then use `elevation` to 0dp on `BottomNavigationView` to handle Z Axis like below:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: That would show it above, but I want it to be shown ahead of. So that `am_tracker_over_layout` overlap `BottomNavigationView` and still be visible completely.

Comment: then use `app:elevation="0dp"`